# save sharedPreferences of inflates checkboxes

Tags: android, android-checkbox, android-sharedpreferences

i inflate layout which have new **check boxes** every time i tabbed buttons,
how can i save the state and (keys,values) of these **check boxes**,
and when i inflate it again retrieve these states,shared-preferences can do that or i should use SQLite database ?

this is the layout iam talking about.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    style="?android:attr/starStyle"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/teamTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/teamTextView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LogoImageView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox"
    android:gravity="center"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="#d3d3d3" >
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/LogoImageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPrefernces` to save and retrieve the `CheckBox` state

```
SharedPrefernces sharedPrefernces = getSharedPreferences(<SharedPreferencesName>, <Mode>);

CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
boolean checkBoxState = checkBox.getChecked();

// Save state in SharedPreferences
SharedPrefernces.Editor editor = sharedPrefernces.edit();
editor.putBoolean(<Key>, state).commit();

// Retrieve CheckBox state from SharedPreferences
boolean checkBoxState = sharedPrefernces.getBoolean(<Key>, <DefaultValue>);
```

Note that you need to call `getSharedPreferences` with a context if you are not calling it inside an `Activity`

Comment: are you understand that the checkboxes will not be existing in any activity after closing this activity? ,because it is changing every time i tabbed new button in the application.

Comment: You will do save/retrieve work after activity is opened. `SharedPreferences` values persist even after closing the app